# Converting a sequence of numbers to conditionals/ranges

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, range

I have an array that consists of pairs of a numeral and some value:

```
a = [[2, :foo], [5, :bar], ..., [17, :baz]]
```

where it can be assumed that no two pairs have the same numeral, and the pairs are sorted by the value of their numeral. Based on this array `a`, I want to pass a numeral `i`, which is always between the minimum and the maximum numerals within `a`, and return the value that is paired with the numeral that is the largest one that does not exceed `i`. Some expected return values are:

```
2 # => :foo
4 # => :foo
5 # => :bar
17 # => :baz
```

What is the best way to do this? Using a hash has a problem handling ranges as a key, and using a `case` statement has difficulty with dynamically adopting to `a`.

Comment: What's the problem with a hash and a range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want logarithmic complexity, you will need to use binary search or some kind of balanced search tree. For simplicity, I suggest the [`rbtree`](http://rbtree.rubyforge.org/) gem:

```
require 'rbtree'

a = [[2, :foo], [5, :bar], [17, :baz]]
t = RBTree[a]

t.upper_bound 4  # => [2, :foo]
t.upper_bound 5  # => [5, :bar]
t.upper_bound 1  # => nil
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. At the moment, this looks the best.

Answer (score 3):

Perfect job for the upcoming [`Range#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) :-) This way you get the right log complexity.

`bsearch` is setup to find a minimum while you want a maximum, so you need to reverse your array. Enjoy:

```
DATA = [[2, :foo], [5, :bar], [12, :hello], [17, :baz]].reverse

def lookup(i)
  nb, val = DATA.bsearch{|nb, val| i >= nb}
  val
end

lookup 2  # => :foo
lookup 4  # => :foo
lookup 5  # => :bar
lookup 17 # => :baz
```

Available today with [`require 'backports/2.0.0'`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) :-)

Comment: Thanks for the nice information. For a day or two, Niklas's answer will be the best, but I will try your backport too. When Ruby 2.0 gets released, I will probably switch to `Range#bsearch` as you suggest. I just found out that this new feature has been waited for long. It should be exciting that it came out.

Comment: I wonder why this feature hasn't been around for all this time because it's almost trivial to implement (although the actual semantics in 2.0 seem to be quite obscure if I interpret Marc's backport correctly).

Comment: @NiklasB. Many features are not in Ruby because there is no agreement on name, functionality, etc... E.g. `nil.to_h` takes one line in C, but generated much discussion before being added to Ruby 2.0.0. And `Enumerable#to_h` didn't make it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get the problem you have with a hash, but if I understood you correctly this works fine.

```
a = [[2, :foo], [5, :bar], [17, :baz]]
h = Hash[a]

class Hash
  def get(i)
    return nil if i < keys.min
    i -= 1 until include?(i)
    self[i]
  end
end

h.get(4) #=> :foo
h.get(5) #=> :bar
h.get(1) #=> nil # No key below 2 exists.
```

Comment: Consider `a = [[1000000000, :foo], [2000000000, :bar]]` in combination with `h.get(1999999999)` :) Also, please don't extend stdlib classes. Instead, use `def h.get` or something equivalent

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, your solution is probably better, upvoted. Though I think it's alright to extend stdlib classes, I agree that `get` is a bit too general, but it's just an example.

Comment: First two `self` are redundant, `min` is inefficient compared to `first`, and would be nicer to use `rindex` instead of your loop... Finally, this is `O(n)` when a `O(log n)` solution exists.

Comment: Extending stdlib classes is fine *as long* as you don't do it in a gem (except gems like `activesupport` which exist specifically for that purpose).

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune I'm still a bit new to Ruby. :) Didn't know about the redundant `self`. `keys` doesn't seem to return an ordered array, so I can't use `first`. How would I replace the loop with `rindex`?

Comment: Welcome to Ruby :-). I meant `first.first`, since `first` gives you the first pair `[nb, val]`. I recommend reading https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide. For `rindex`, I'll let you work :-)

Comment: Well, I'm not that new, already read the guide some months ago. The first pair, doesn't have to be the one with the lowest key? `{5 => :f, 1 => :a}.first.first #=> 5`

Comment: @js-coder: No, hash tables have no inherent order. In Ruby 1.9, though, they preserve insertion order (or in this case, the order in which you specified the items in the literal). So `keys.first != keys.min` in general, unless you ensure that you insert the elements in sorted order (you could do `Hash[a.sort_by(&:first)]`). That would prevent you from adding new elements, though. I think what Marc was hinting at is that a hash is unnecessary here because you actually don't use the fast lookup it provides. You could instead iterate over `a` directly.